# writing a (very) generic equality comparer

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, expression

I have a data stucture that is straightforward serializable (e.g. to XML, to JSON): There is a main class `C1` and several other classes `C2`, `C3`, ..., `Cn`. All classes `Ci` have `public` properties which are either

- primitive types or `string`
- `IEnumerable<T>` where `T` is either primitive type or `string` or any of the classes `Cj` (where `j != i`)
- `Cj` (where `j != i`)

There are no circular references.

I want to define a generic equality comparer `ValueEqualityComparer<T>` which compares any of the classes `Ci` value-wise, i.e. in the following canonical way:

- if type `T` is primitive, use `Equals` (or `==`)
- if type `T` is `IEnumerable<S>`, use `Enumerable.SequenceEqual` on the `S` objects with a `ValueEqualityComparer<S>` as third argument
- else, for each public property `P` use `ValueEqualityComparer<P>.Equals` and connect these results via `&&`.

I already learned that pattern matching like above is not possible directly, so I need reflection. But I am struggling with how to do that.

Here is what I have written so far:

```
public class ValueEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    public static readonly ValueEqualityComparer<T> Get = new ValueEqualityComparer<T>();
    private static readonly Type _type = typeof(T);
    private static readonly bool _isPrimitiveOrString = IsPrimitiveOrString(_type);
    private static readonly Type _enumerableElementType = GetEnumerableElementTypeOrNull(_type);
    private static bool _isEnumerable => _enumerableElementType != null;

    private ValueEqualityComparer() {}

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            if (x == null && y == null)
                return true;
            return false;
        }

        if (_isPrimitive)
            return x.Equals(y);

        if (_isEnumerable)
        {
            var comparerType = typeof(ValueEqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(new Type[] { _enumerableElementType });
            var elementComparer = comparerType.GetField("Get").GetValue(null);

            // not sure about this line:
            var result = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "SequenceEqual", new Type[] { _enumerableElementType },
                new Expression[] { Expression.Constant(x), Expression.Constant(y), Expression.Constant(elementComparer) });
        }

        // TODO: iterate public properties, use corresponding ValueEqualityComparers
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        // TODO
    }

    private static bool IsPrimitiveOrString(Type t) => t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string);

    // if we have e.g. IEnumerable<string>, it will return string
    private static Type GetEnumerableElementTypeOrNull(Type t)
    {
        Type enumerableType = t.GetInterfaces().Where(i => i.IsGenericType
            && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>)).FirstOrDefault();
        return enumerableType?.GetGenericArguments().Single();
    }
}
```

Questions regarding the `// not sure about this line:` line:

- The goal is to call `Enumerable.SequenceEqual<S>(x, y, ValueEqualityComparer<S>.Get)` where `S` is the element type of `x` and `y` (i.e. `T` is `IEnumerable<S>`). Is the line I wrote correct for that purpose?
- How do I get the result (i.e. `true` or `false`) of that call?

Please don't fill in the `// TODO` sections; I want to figure out as much as I can for myself.

I do not want to compare serialized objects because it will not aid much in debugging. The comparer is needed for testing, after all.

Comment: Nothing in the rules you've stated prevents `Cx` having a `Cy` and `Cy` having a `Cx`. Is such a situation (or larger cycles) actually allowed? If so, how would you propose to prevent infinite regression?

Comment: Regarding the section where you said "All classes `Ci` have public properties which are either..." Do you mean that there will be no circular references? From the way you have currently written it, circular references will still be possible. `C1` could have a `C2` property, and `C2` could have a `C1` property, and two objects could refer to each other, and it will potentially cause infinite recursion.

Comment: Why not simply serialize both `x` and `y` and compare the serialization results?

Comment: I don't think `Expression.Call` is correct, IMO you should get the [`MethodInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo?view=netcore-3.1) of `SequenceEqual` and then use [`MethodInfo.Invoke`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.methodinfo.invoke?view=netframework-1.1)

Comment: `return Equals(x, y)` looks problematic.. potentially an infinite loop.  If I were attempt this, I think I would work with overload methods, castings, and review on polymorphic behavior.. probably Tuple.Create for GetHashCode overload method as well..

Comment: Have you considered comparing the Serialized output instead. This kind of meta programming is not simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MindSwipe's comment I got it. Just replace the `// not sure about this line:` line by the following code snippet:

```
// generic methods cannot be retrieved by the current GetMethod() api, this is a common workaround:
var sequenceEqualNongeneric = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(
    m => m.Name == "SequenceEqual" && m.GetParameters().Length == 3).Single();
var sequenceEqualGeneric = sequenceEqualNongeneric.MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { _enumerableElementType });
return (bool)sequenceEqualGeneric.Invoke(null, new object[] { x, y, elementComparer });
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so it took a little playing around, but I think I got it, here goes nothing.

---

### For primitives and strings

Firstly, if it's a primitive or string, you can simply call `left.Equals(right)` (I decided to call the parameters `left` and `right` instead of `x` and `y`, just because)

---

### For IEnumerables

Then, if it's an enumerable, things get more involved. Firstly we need to make a generic Type for our new `ValueEqualityComparer`, after that we get it's constructor and construct a new one (this step could possibly be enhanced by caching (in a `Dictionary`) previous equality comparers by type, so if a lot of one type get compared after another, we wouldn't need to create a new comparer every time). We then need to get the `SequenceEquals` method, make it generic and call it with our `left`, `right` and `elementComparer`.

---

### For every other type

For every other type we want to compare property by property, we first need to get all the properties for the given type. Then we need to iterate over every property, get value of the property from `left` and `right`, create our generic `ValueEqualityComparer`, get its `Equal` method, and finally call said `Equal` method with our `leftProp` and `rightProp`

---

### All together now:

This results in this class:

```cs
public class ValueEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Type _enumerableElementType;
    private readonly bool _isEnumerable;
    private readonly bool _isPrimitiveOrString;
    
    public ValueEqualityComparer()
    {
        var type = typeof(T);
        _isPrimitiveOrString = IsPrimitiveOrString(type);

        // Only check if it's an enumerable,
        // if the current type to compare is not a primitive or string
        if (!_isPrimitiveOrString)
            (_isEnumerable, _enumerableElementType) = IsEnumerableAndElementType(type);
    }

    public bool Equals(T left, T right)
    {
        if (_isPrimitiveOrString)
            return left?.Equals(right) ?? false;

        if (_isEnumerable)
        {
            // Make generic ValueEqualityComparer type for type of element of enumerable and construct it
            // Possibly cache this
            var elementComparer = typeof(ValueEqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(_enumerableElementType)
                .GetConstructor(new Type[] { })?.Invoke(null);

            // Get the SequenceEqual method and make it generic for our element type
            // SequenceEqual methods may also be cached for better performance
            var sequenceEquals = typeof(Enumerable).Assembly.GetTypes()
                .Where(assemblyType =>
                    assemblyType.IsSealed && !assemblyType.IsGenericType && !assemblyType.IsNested)
                .SelectMany(assemblyType => assemblyType.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public),
                    (assemblyType, method) => new {assemblyType, method})
                .Where(x => x.method.IsDefined(typeof(ExtensionAttribute), false))
                .First(x => x.method.Name == nameof(Enumerable.SequenceEqual) &&
                            x.method.GetParameters().Length == 3)
                .method
                .MakeGenericMethod(_enumerableElementType);

            // This is basically like calling left.SequenceEqual(right, elementComparer);
            // Cast to bool, as SequenceEqual returns a bool
            return (bool) sequenceEquals.Invoke(null, new[] {left, right, elementComparer});
        }

        // T is not an Enumerable, and not a primitive or a string, so get all public instance properties and compare them
        // We ignore private and static properties here
        var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        foreach (var property in properties)
        {
            // Get the values of left and right property
            var leftProp = property.GetValue(left);
            var rightProp = property.GetValue(right);

            var propComparerType = typeof(ValueEqualityComparer<>).MakeGenericType(property.PropertyType);
            var propComparer = propComparerType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { })?.Invoke(null);

            var equalsMethod = propComparerType.GetMethod(nameof(Equals),
                new[] {property.PropertyType, property.PropertyType});

            if (equalsMethod == null)
                continue;

            // If any of the properties don't equal one another, return false early
            if (!(bool) equalsMethod.Invoke(propComparer, new[] {leftProp, rightProp}))
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T x)
    {
        return Tuple.Create(_isEnumerable, _enumerableElementType, _isPrimitiveOrString)
            .GetHashCode();
    }

    private static bool IsPrimitiveOrString(Type t)
    {
        return t.IsPrimitive || t == typeof(string);
    }

    private static (bool, Type) IsEnumerableAndElementType(Type t)
    {
        var enumerableType = t.GetInterfaces()
            .FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsGenericType && x.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>));

        return (enumerableType != null, enumerableType?.GetGenericArguments().Single());
    }
}
```

[Here's](https://dotnetfiddle.net/LcKuGe) a link to a dotnetfiddle containing this, as well as some tests

Comment: You say "after that we get it's constructor and construct a new one (this step could possibly be enhanced by caching (in a Dictionary) previous equality comparers by type, so if a lot of one type get compared after another, we wouldn't need to create a new comparer every time)" - because of that, I made most stuff static and use the static `Get()` method instead of a constructor.

Comment: Well, in your constructor, which is called every time you call `Get()`, you recreate it anyways. So there really isn't any difference in not using `Get()`. What I meant is a private static Dictionary which caches `ValueEqualityComparer<T>` where the Key is `T`, if that would be implemented the `Get()` would have a reason to exist, namely to check the cache first, and only create a new one if it's not cached yet. But as my answer stands right now, there is no reason for a `Get()` method

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I meant to have a static field for `Get`, not method. Corrected it. That way the constructor is called once per `T` actually used, and subseqeuent calls just reuse it. No need for dictionary now.

Comment: @Kjara I ran a quick benchmark with one version implementing the `Get` and a basic LRU cache, one version implementing `Get` with the static properties and one without any fancy stuff. Turns out: Cached has a mean of 234.3µs with an error of 4.32µs, Static Get has a mean of 227.8µs and a error of 4.26µs and good ol' regular constructing it everytime has a mean of 227.2µs and an error of 1.93µs (lower is of course better)

Comment: should also include `IEnumerable<T>.Intersect` and `IEnumerable<T>.Except` with your testing, passing the `IEqualityComparer<T>` instance (which I believe will test `GetHashCode` implementation)

Comment: also `IEnumerable<T>.Distinct(IEqualityComparer<T>)` and `IEnumerable<T>.GroupBy(..., IEqualityComparer<T>)` should be tested.. note that there may be some scenarios where `Distinct` is actually called implicitly and you cannot pass a comparer.. (though I don't recall what scenario I ran into at the moment)  the only way I'm aware to work around that is by overriding `GetHashCode` on the enumerated type's implementation and using the instance of your comparer in that scope..